# How can i solve this question from my computer organization homework?

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

i tried almost everything but i couldn't solve this question. I wrote an assembly code that outputs first 12 fibbonaci numbers. And found the instruction counts, here's the table for:

[image: table to solve question:]

and here is the question:

> Assume we introduce a second level cache (a cache between the primary
>   cache and main memory). And we have the following numbers for the new
>   configuration:
>
> Access time (Cache 2)= 20 Clock Cycles
>
> Global miss rate to main memory = 2 %
>
> Considering the above values,
>
> a)Calculate the total clock cycles spent according to table.
>
> b)What is the average clock cycle per instruction now?

Comment: Does your architecture not have a store buffer to decouple store execution from commit to L1d cache?  Fibonacci doesn't need to load any data, *just* store and update registers.  And storing contiguous data has ideal spatial locality.  The only loads should be from code fetch, but a Fib loop should probably fit in a single line of I-cache and stay hot across iterations.  But I guess you're supposed to pretend that a 2% miss rate for both code fetch and data store is representative of your loop?

Comment: Without knowing the inner caches's average miss rates, I'm not sure we can say anything useful about what difference adding an L2 cache will make.  Unless the perf numbers in your image already account for L1-I$ misses, and for lw/sw L1-D$ misses?

Comment: i can add the code if it is usefull

Comment: Instruction counts are fine, although lw/sw counts seem high for 1 iteration of Fibonacci.  Maybe you're reloading recent stores instead of using registers.  (But regardless of how much locality you create with redundant code, this question still tells you to assume the same miss rate, I guess?  Whatever, it's just an unrealistic exercise that adds up cycle counts without considering any instruction-level parallelism or latency vs. throughput.)

Comment: I think the piece of info that's lacking is the L1 miss rate.  We know how long it take to access L2 on an L2 hit or L2 miss.  And we have the 2% L2 misses out of all accesses.  But not the fraction of L1 miss / L2 hit out of all total accesses.  So we don't know how much speedup we're getting over the numbers in your table.  Are you sure there wasn't some cache hit rate info in your textbook that those cycle counts per instruction were based on?